# Check each index of array if value of index is numeric print next index value - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check each index of array if its value is numeric print next key

```
print_r($expkey);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => ew-language
    [1] => en
    [2] => 0
    [3] => phrase
    [4] => locale
)

Array
(
    [0] => ew-language
    [1] => en
    [2] => phrase
    [3] => 1
    [4] => use_system_locale
)
```

when `[2] => 0`
print `phrase`
when `[3] => 1`
print `use_system_locale`

```
function numeric($key) {
$i=0;
if(is_numeric(key($key))){
 $i++;
 //if($i = ) incomplete code for function 
}
}
 numeric($expkey);
```

HOW TO DO IT ? THANK YOU FOR HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through it and check. if succeed then print next value -

```
foreach($your_array as $key=>$value) {
    foreach($value as $key => $check_val) {
      if(is_numeric($check_val)) {
        echo $value[$ley+1];
      }
    }
}
```

You need to take care of the `kay`s also.

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
foreach($expkey as $key->$value)
{
    if(is_numeric($value))
    {
        $next_val = $expkey[$i+1];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Warning:  Attempt to assign property of non-object

Answer (score 1):

Just another answer:

```
<?php
function getValueNextToFirstNumeric($arr) {
    for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
        if(is_numeric($arr[$i]) && isset($arr[$i+1]))
            return $arr[$i+1];
    }
    return null;
}

// Your array:
$arr = array
(
    ['ew-language', 'en', 0, 'phrase', 'locale'],
    ['ew-language', 'en', 'phrase', 1, 'use_system_locale'],
    ['ew-language', 'en', 2, 'phrase', 'decimal_point']
);
foreach($arr as $a)
    echo getValueNextToFirstNumeric($a) ."<br />";
?>
```